# ElasticSearch docker container remains in Exited status

Tags: linux, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

Recently installed Docker, ElasticSearch 7.17.6. `docker-compose up -d` worked fine

but when trying to bring up the ElasticSearch container, its status remains Exited(1) & can't start the container.
Command to start: `sudo docker container start <container-ID>`

See below Exception for command: `sudo docker logs <Container-ID>`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:218)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:380)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:432)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:422)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:160)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.readJvmOptionsFiles(JvmOptionsParser.java:168)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:124)
        at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:86)
```

var/log/messages file shows below error:

```
msg="error detaching from network es_elastic: could not find network attachment for container <Container-ID> to network es_elastic"
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 dockerd: time="2022-11-01T13:11:07.567246932-04:00" level=info msg="initialized VXLAN UDP port to 4789 "
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: br0: port 2(<Device_name2>) entered disabled state
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: br0: port 1(<Device_name1>) entered disabled state
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: ov-1-f: renamed from br0
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: device <Device_name2> left promiscuous mode
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: ov-1-f: port 2(<Device_name2>) entered disabled state
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: device <Device_name1> left promiscuous mode
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: ov-1-f: port 1(<Device_name1>) entered disabled state
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: vx-1-f: renamed from <Device_name1>
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: : renamed from <Device_name2>
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 avahi-daemon[891]: Withdrawing workstation service for vx-1-f.
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 NetworkManager[999]: <info>  [ID.7289] manager: (): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/144)
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 kernel: : renamed from eth0
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 NetworkManager[999]: <info>  [ID.7693] manager: (): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/145)
Nov  1 13:11:07 ES11 dockerd: time="2022-11-01T13:11:07.ID-04:00" level=warning msg="Error (Unable to complete atomic operation, key modified) deleting object
```

Comment: when runs this command, gets the same excpetion while attaching es11 'sudo docker-compose up --force-recreate'
Error:'WARNING: The Docker Engine you're using is running in swarm mode.
Compose does not use swarm mode to deploy services to multiple nodes in a swarm. All containers will be scheduled on the current node.

To deploy your application across the swarm, use `docker stack deploy`.

Recreating es11 ... done
Attaching to es11
es11    | Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/jvm.options'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File jvm.options were missing from the config directory at /u01/es11/config but unsure why the error shows different location and how come it worked in other nodes es12 & es13. But containers started fine after placing these files.